# Ubuntu Desktop fails to boot on Raspberry Pi 400 with 32GB SD card

Tags: boot, boot-issues, ubuntu, mount, filesystem

I have used Pi Imager to write Ubuntu Desktop to my SD card. When I try to boot from it in my Pi 400, I get the following error:

```
[50B]: Failed to remount '/' read-only: Device or resource busy
systemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize filesystems, ignoring.
```

and then the Pi shuts down. The first time I booted, I also saw Ubuntu logo and the spinner icon but I can't remember if it was at the very beginning of the boot or just prior to the shutdown (I suspect the latter) but it is no longer showing.

Since I was able to boot into Raspbian from another card, I inserted the Ubuntu card through an USB card reader and both partitions created by Pi imager on that Ubuntu SD card are visible, readable and writable: I was able to create a backup copy of `firstrun.sh` and then remove it (as I suspected that it might be causing issues and I also wanted to confirm that the card is writeable).

`fsck` does not throw any errors for either partition so it looks like filesystem is not corrupted.

What could be the reason the system fails to boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the source of the issue thanks to these two posts from Pi's forums:

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=248968

It turns out, I flashed the image on 32GB microSD card which I put into microSD-SD adapter which I then inserted into SD card reader "port" in a laptop and even though all files required for boot seemed to be there, apparently something in that chain of adapters/readers didn't fully support SDXC standard needed to flash the image on this 32GB card correctly.

I re-flashed the card using Pi Imager and microSD reader inserted into USB port of Pi 400 and Ubuntu booted fine.

Now I have an issue with the desktop environment which I link to below just in case someone who solved the boot issue thanks to this also experiences the same issue with desktop environments on Ubuntu on Pi in general:

[Ubuntu desktop environments freezing on Pi 400](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/132683/ubuntu-desktop-environments-freezing-on-pi-400)